# Возможно ли передать в метод результат метода экземпляра класса?

Tags: java, сортировка

Имеется класс `AnyClass` с конструктором, задающим по умолчанию значение переменной `a` типа `int` и методом `getInt()`, возвращающим значение переменной `a`:

```
class AnyClass{
    private int a = 10;

    public int getInt(){
        return this.a;
    }

    AnyClass(){
        this.a = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    }
}
```

Создаем 10 экземпляров класса:

```
AnyClass ac = new AnyClass[10];
for(int i = 0; i < AnyClass.length; i++)
    ac[i] = new AnyClass();
```

Как известно, имеется класс `Arrays` с методом `sort()`, выполняющим сортировку в алфавитном порядке - `Arrays.sort()`. В нашем случае он будет принимать `массив int'ов`.

**Вопрос:** возможно ли передать в метод sort() возвращаемое значение метода экземпляра класса, типа так:

```
Arrays.sort(ac.getInt());
```

Если нет, то каким образом это лучше всего организовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(ac, (a, b) -> a.getInt() - b.getInt());
```

---

```
Arrays.sort(ac, (AnyClass a, AnyClass b) -> {
  return a.getInt() - b.getInt();
});
```

---

```
Arrays.sort(ac, new Comparator<AnyClass>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(AnyClass a, AnyClass b) {
    return a.getInt().compareTo(b.getInt());
  }
});
```

Comment: Расшифруйте синтаксис, пожалуйста

Comment: И ещё интересен нюанс, если нужно будет передавать не int, а String?

Comment: @n199a `a.getString().compareTo(b.getString())`

Comment: Напишите полную строку, пожалуйста `Arrays.sort(...` . Мне непонятен пока синтаксис, какие разделы в учебниках Java, документацию нужно для этого прочитать, чтобы отпали такого рода вопросы у меня? А то не выходит `Arrays.sort(ac, (a, b) -> a.(тут_название_метода).getString().compareTo(b.(тут_название_метода).getString())`

Comment: @n199a `Arrays.sort(ac, (a, b) -> a.getString().compareTo(b.getString()));`

Comment: Как сравнить значения типа `long`? Это `Arrays.sort(obj, (a, b)->Math.max(a.getOtherLong(), b.getOtherLong()))` и это `Arrays.sort(obj, (a, b) -> a.getOtherLong().compareTo(b.getOtherLong()));` не выходит.